# Однородные глагольные части составного сказуемого и порядок слов

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые, однородные-члены

В последнее время очень часто встречаюсь с таким порядком слов в предложениях с составным сказуемым:

"**За происходящим** можно наблюдать онлайн через мобильное приложение либо пользоваться архивом".

"**Умные устройства** можно оснастить дополнительными модулями, а также подключить функцию видеонаблюдения".

Настолько часто, что уже начинаю сомневаться в себе: может быть, действительно, так можно сказать?
В моем представлении объект, вынесенный в начало предложения, автоматически должен относиться ко всему сказуемому (можно наблюдать либо пользоваться, можно оснастить и подключить), но вторая часть сказуемого в обоих случаях дополнительно распространяется уже без учета общего объекта.

Где бы найти правила?

Comment: Умные устройства можно оснастить дополнительными модулями, а также можно подключить В НИХ функцию видеонаблюдения. -- Здесь просто опущено "в них".  

"За происходящим можно наблюдать онлайн через мобильное приложение, либо можно пользоваться архивом С ЭТОЙ ЦЕЛЬЮ"
Здесь просто пропущено "для этого".
Ну оформить эти двухосновные сложные предложения через одну основу, я не вижу криминала:
"Можно следить за происходящим либо закрыть на него глаза."

Comment: А смена порядка слов здесь не меняет грамматики. Для русского это редкость

Comment: @user190920 Нельзя пропускать "в них", потому что можно понять как "к ним" (учитывая подключение модулей к устройствам) или как-то ещё. *Здесь просто пропущено "для этого"* — во-первых, там пропущено слово "можно" (а у вас почему-то нет).

Comment: Вопрос не столько в том, как это можно исправить, сколько в том, корректны ли эти фразы, и если нет, то почему нет. Я, может быть, слишком закапываюсь, но я вижу проблему именно со структурой предложения, где автор выносит дополнение в препозицию, а все остальное оставляет как есть. Поправьте меня,  если я ошибаюсь, но объект в такой ситуации становится детерминантом, а значит нельзя во второй части предложения взять и заменить его другим объектом, как в примере с умными устройствами. Проблема в том, что такие конструкции встречаются слишком часто и будто бы никого, кроме меня, не смущают.

Comment: @user190920 порядок слов определяет возможность построения однородного ряда и допустимость эллипсиса.

Comment: Да, видимо, это не корректно, если исходить из структуры с одним составным сказуемым. Но если сказать, что у нас два составных сказуемых, тогда эти предложения корректны (с учетом простановки запятой). Хотя слишком многое в них опущено - звучат как скороговорки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для тех, кто не понимает, что происходит и что обсуждается вообще.

**Начало простого предложения должно быть общим.** Во всяком случае для инфинитивов.

Пример:
*Собаку можно гладить и играться.* || Форма "собаку" не подходит для "играться", поэтому предложение не корректно.
В разговорной речи могут игнорировать необщее начало таким образом:
*Собаку можно гладить и играться с ней.* || Хоть смысл и понятен, структура не корректна.
Исправляется добавлением второго "можно":
*Собаку можно гладить, и можно играться с ней.*
либо переносом необщего слова "собаку" за инфинитив:
*Можно гладить собаку и играться с ней.*

Более ярко недопустимость необщего начала заметна здесь:
*В спортзале Васе нравится бегать и ходить за грибами.*
Переносим необщее начало, и предложение становится корректным:
*Васе нравится бегать в спортзале и ходить за грибами.*

Answer (score 0):

Первый пример корректен, но "за происходящим" не является общим элементом, и нужна запятая. Смысл такой:
*За происходящим можно наблюдать онлайн через мобильное приложение, либо [тогда уже] пользоваться архивом.*
Это равносильно отдельным предложениям:
*За происходящим можно наблюдать онлайн через мобильное приложение. Либо пользоваться архивом.*

А второй уже нет. Отдельными предложениями такое уже не записать. А если считать глаголы однородными, то получается следующее:
*Умные устройства можно подключить функцию видеонаблюдения.*
Скорее всего, там что-то пропущено. Сказать что наверняка нельзя (поэтому так и писать нельзя). Наверно, это "можно" и "к ним":
*Умные устройства можно оснастить дополнительными модулями, а также [можно] подключить [к ним] функцию видеонаблюдения.*
Не всегда можно опускать слова. Здесь это стилистическая ошибка (не хватает слов для того, чтобы однозначно понять мысль), а ещё грамматическая (нет стыковки однородных элементов либо простых предложений с "а также").

Примечание: "можно" нельзя считать общим элементом, потому что тогда общим будет и то, что до него, — "умные устройства можно".

Comment: _Либо пользоваться архивом_, только потому что перед ним стоит запятая или точка, не становится же самостоятельным предложением. Такое допустимо разве что в разговорной речи, на мой взгляд. Ну и еще _в архиве_ мы не _наблюдаем за происходящим_ -- но это уже другая проблема. Вообще, я перерыла весь интернет в поисках какого-нибудь правила о том, как обращаться с однородными частями составного глагольного сказуемого, чтобы доказать мою точку зрения, но ничего не нашла. Тянет уже перейти к аргументам про актуальное членение предложения, но не хотелось бы :))

Comment: Его **допустимо** оформить как самостоятельное предложение, дело в этом. Разговорная речь — да, всё именно так. Может, смысл не тот, который вы видите: было бы неплохо, если бы вы исправили это предложение — чтобы сравнить с тем, как должно быть.

Comment: Я бы переписала так: "За происходящим можно наблюдать через мобильное приложение, а если нужно просмотреть прошедшие события, то можно воспользоваться архивом".

Comment: *а если нужно просмотреть прошедшие события* — вот оно что. Может, об этом раньше говорилось, но по этому предложению так не понять, о предназначении архива вообще не сказано.

Comment: Это мое предположение только. Через приложение можно наблюдать в прямом эфире, а в архиве, наверное, пересматривать позже.

Comment: Да, это логично. Но для этих целей предложение грамматически корректно (чего не скажешь про второй случай из-за "а также", которое должно что-то соединять), просто надо домыслить, только нужно поставить запятую, чтобы не относить "за происходящим можно" к "пользоваться архивом".

Comment: @creativecommas В первом примере всё просто: с запятой либо с точкой "можно" может подразумеваться. Во втором примере этому препятствует некорректная структура, которая образовывается из-за "а также".

Comment: Проблема в том, что эллипсис обычно используется в одинаково построенных структурах. Например, "В спортзале Васе нравится бегать, Саше - прыгать". (_Саше нравится прыгать в спортзале_). Но предположим, мы хотим сказать, что Васе нравится бегать в спортзале и ходить за грибами, и мы выделяем "в спортзале" таким способом: "_**В спортзале** Васе нравится бегать, либо ходить за грибами"_. Получается чушь. Так же и в первом примере детерминант относится к обеим частям: _"За происходящим можно наблюдать через мобильное приложение, за происходящим можно пользоваться архивом"_.

Comment: В примере со спортзалом да (чушь). Кстати, классный пример, надо бы Sharon показать. А в первом примере похоже на следующее: *За происходящим можно наблюдать онлайн через мобильное приложение, либо используй архив.* То есть оно самостоятельно, там может что-то подразумеваться, но можно и без этого (нет эллипсиса). Да, такое характерно для разговорного стиля, но оно корректно.

Comment: Про разговорный не спорю!

Comment: Запятая в первом предложении поставлена ОШИБОЧНО, это простое предложение, а не сложное. "Если сочиняются именные части сказуемого {Этой осенью погода была холодная, дождливая) или инфинитивы в составном глагольном сказуемом {Он любит купаться и загорать), предложение считается простым стр. 111:https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf

Comment: @Sharon Запятую оправдываем присоединением (которое вынуждено).

Comment: @creativecommas Проблема ещё в том, что, чем длиннее предложение, тем менее очевидна эта ошибка, тем лучше оно звучит. Это из-за того, что далёкое исчезает из оперативной памяти и мысленного фокуса. Чем ближе элементы, тем проще мозгу выявить грамматическую нестыковку.