# Обоснованность запятой перед «и»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, и

Нужна ли запятая в предложении?
*Этому я у мастера училась, **и** сама старалась учить этому.*
Мое мнение, что запятая тут нужна, но другие филологи так не считают. Я считаю, что это сложное предложение, где в первой части предложения *я* — подлежащее, *училась* — сказуемое, во второй части *сама* — подлежащее, *старалась учить* — сказуемое.
Очень важно третье мнение по этому поводу.

Comment: Обосновать можно присоединением. Например, можно оформить двумя предложениями: *Этому я у мастера училась. И сама старалась учить этому.*

Comment: Да, можно и так. Это хитрый способ, но правильный.

Comment: В таких случаях есть варианты (простое — одна мысль, сложное — две мысли). Но здесь, если простое предложение, использование "этому" в качестве детерминанта (в начале) не очень корректно в плане структуры. Вот так структура нормальная: *Этому я училась и сама учила. Я училась этому у мастера и сама старалась учить этому.* А запятая устраняет неполадки со структурой.

Comment: Структуру простого предложения нарушает "этому" в конце, первое "этому" относится к подлежащему, а следовательно, и к каждому глаголу. В этом и заключается то нарушение порядка слов, о котором говорили другие филологи. Структура корректна так: *Этому я у мастера училась и сама старалась учить (этому училась и старалась учить).* Если предложение сложное (есть запятая), то ничего исправлять не надо.

Comment: У слов ‟сам”, ‟сама”, ‟само” где-то 50 значений. Вот пара из них: 1. В предложениях: ‟Тебе помочь” — ‟Нет, я справлюсь сам” — слово ‟сам” имеет такое же значение, как и у слова ‟самостоятельно”; можно заменить на: ‟Я справлюсь самостоятельно”. 2. В предложении: ‟В комнату вошёл сам король” — ‟сам” обозначает значимость обозначаемого словом, к которому ‟сам” относится. 3. В предложении: ‟Мы отдохнем скоро, я сам очень устал, — но сейчас мы не можем” — ‟сам” обозначает то же самое, что и ‟тоже” и ‟также”. 4. В предложении: ‟Я не насиловал её, она само хотела” — слово ‟сама” обозначает

Comment: невынужденное, добровольное решение. 5. В предложении: ‟Я сам не могу починить этот прибор, а что уже говорить о ней” — слово ‟сам” обозначает то же самое, что и частица ‟даже”.  И так далее. Нужно много времени, чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, чтобы выявить то самое значение, что и в вашем вопросе.

Comment: @JimKorbett Для этого словари есть. Не вам значения выявлять.

Answer (score 2):

Вот что имеется в МАС:
[сам](http://endic.ru/academic/Sam-55576.html)
*самого́, м.; сама́, само́й, вин. самоё и саму́, ж.; само́, самого́, ср.; мн. са́ми, сами́х; мест. определит.*
Для указания на лицо или предмет, участвующие в действии самостоятельно, без чьей-либо помощи или вмешательства или невольно, непроизвольно.
*— Я работаю от утра до ночи. Все прививки я делаю сам, обрезку — сам, посадки — сам, все — сам.* Чехов, Черный монах.

Считаю, что запятая в вашем предложении не нужна, если подразумевается именно это значение (смущает только повтор слова "этому", я бы заменила одно на конкретное — чему); однородные сказуемые "училась" и "старалась учить".
*Этому я у мастера училась и сама старалась учить этому.*

Вот, думаю, подходящий пример из Нацкорпуса.
Понимая, сколь важное значение имеет попытка сделать такую большую и нужную работу, я всячески подбивал на нее Александра Николаевича, посылал и привозил ему книги **и сам старался прочесть** как можно больше книг своих периферийных товарищей... [Виктор Астафьев. Зрячий посох (1978-1982)]

Comment: Большое спасибо Вам! Очень помогли мне в этом непростом вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

**Этому я у мастера училась и сама старалась учить этому.**

*Сама* не является подлежащим, о чём у Розенталя имеется ремарка ("Пунктуация", § 30.1, примеч.):

> *Автор прочитал корректуру и сам внёс нужные исправления* — предложение    простое, а слово "сам" не является подлежащим.

Comment: Спасибо, тогда и вы ловите тоже.  За любовь к языку, к знаниям и ко всему новому.  И про "информационное поле" мы, как я надеюсь,  еще поговорим. Мне кажется, что каждая наука, и русская грамматика в том числе,  имеет такое поле,  где уже  есть все ответы и все решения.

Comment: @Sharon увы, не поговорим) Кое-кто на этом сайте меня на дух не переносит, а я стараюсь не находиться там, где меня не терпят.

Comment: Мне все это хорошо знакомо (я несколько раз уходила с форума, но потом все-таки возвращалась). Не общайтесь с людьми, которые вам неприятны, не разговаривайте с ними вообще, и тогда они отстанут. Так уж устроен мир, от этого никуда не уйдешь.  Они  любят только себе подобных...

Comment: @Sharon возможно, это я люблю только себе подобных, а мои критики правы. Эффект Даннинга — Крюгера может быть и обратным: не самоуверенное невежество, а самонеуверенное знание... В любом случае я есть в Телеграм под тем же ником; если вдруг будет не с кем что-то обсудить — стучитесь, и отворят вам, amen :)

Comment: Please come back, it's empty and sad here without you. And I'll be waiting for you, can I?

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: ***Этому я у мАстера училась и самА старалась учить этому***.

Это простое предложение с однородными сказуемыми. Предикативная основа: Я училась и старалась учить.  Запятая не нужна.

Слово ***сама*** является местоименным прилагательным.

Из словаря: **САМ II. местоим. прил**. 1. Подчёркивает, что речь идёт о данном лице или предмете; именно он и никто другой, именно оно и ничто другое. В этом вопросе будет разбираться **сам президент**. Нарушен не подзаконный акт, а **сам закон**. Фальсифицирован не текст, а **сама идея**! Автор изображает **саму жизнь** и такой, какая она есть. Внушите это **ему самому**, а не нам.

***Я сама*** – прилагательное в роли определения к слову "я" в роли подлежащего.
Инверсияя слов определяет нужную расстановку ударений.

Comment: Ловите плюсик :) Я многому у вас научился, спасибо!

Comment: Поставил бы запятую, чтобы обозначить разные ситуации, а то и интонационное тире.

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь! Вы меня убедили, что ставить запятую не надо. Случай для меня оказался не таким простым: сбило с толку, что слово САМА находится слишком далеко от слова Я, действия происходят в разное время, интонация в первой части предложения и второй части разная.  Ох, какой непростой у нас язык!

Comment: @Наталья У вас есть хоть какая-то пауза перед "и" при чтении?

Comment: У меня нет паузы.

Comment: См. мой ответ: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467890 Здесь такая же история. Детерминант нельзя повторять в простом предложении, так что делаем сложное с помощью запятой.

Comment: Все истории разные, нет ни одной похожей))  Просмотрела я последние вопросы... Много интересных!  Но ответы...  Где тонкое чувство языка, где ясное понимание структуры предложения?  А вы как думаете, oleedd,
все ли там у вас как надо?

Comment: Не понимаю вопрос. Где у меня? Обратите внимание на этот вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473077 Вы любите править, как раз для вас. Но исправить надо минимально, в идеале просто заменить неудачное слово (о нём сказано в задании).

Comment: Это я случайно не про то написала, про другой ваш ответ. А такие темы я сразу прохожу мимо, 17 вопросов!  Я столько и не прочитаю!  Хороший вопрос – это один вопрос!

Comment: Какой именно ответ? Оба ответа про детерминант правильные. Ну тогда обратите внимание на 1, 5 и 10. Остальное исправить гораздо проще.

Comment: Времени нет!  И со старыми темами я не люблю работать. Из новых мне не понравилась тема https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473083/Нужна-ли-запятая-в-предложении-Жена-молчаливо-сидит-за-праздничным-столом-сильн   Ваши комментарии там тоже есть.  Особенно присоединительная конструкция, о которой все говорят , И вариант там верен только один, его надо вычислить по структуре предложения.

Comment: Вчерашняя — это старая? Почти свежая. У вас здесь такая структура получается: *Собаку я у мастера гладила и сама игралась с собакой.* Это неправильная структура. Да, по структуре, там вариант с запятой вообще не надо рассматривать. Он начал спорить, не хватает вашего ответа.

Comment: Думаю, вам надо там ответить, чтобы расставить все точки. Уже не раз о таком спрашивали, уже надоело. Даже попрошу автора вопроса переставить галочку вам.

Comment: И вообще, предложение надо редактировать, ужасный порядок слов, не русский. Надо так: *Сильно расстроенная, жена молчаливо сидит за праздничным столом.*